# How do I listen for changes on the selected shipping method for checkout ui extensions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I have a checkout ui extension text input field. It is rendered on the same page as the shipping methods. I need to be able to store the state of the selected shipping method for validation purposes. However, my current useEffect is not running when the customer changes the selected shipping method, as the deliveryGroup reference value does not change.

How can I update the state of the selectedDeliveryOption every time the customer changes it? Thank you!

```
import {
  useExtensionApi,
  render,
  TextField,
  useApplyAttributeChange,
} from '@shopify/checkout-ui-extensions-react';

render('Checkout::Dynamic::Render', () => <App />);

function App() {
  const { deliveryGroups } = useExtensionApi();
  const [shippingAccountInfo, setShippingAccountInfo] = useState('');
  const [selectedDeliveryOption, setSelectedDeliveryOption] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Check if deliveryGroups and deliveryGroups.current are defined, and if deliveryGroups.current has at least one item
    if (deliveryGroups && deliveryGroups.current && deliveryGroups.current.length > 0) {
      // Extract the handle of the selectedDeliveryOption from the first item in the current array
      const handle = deliveryGroups.current[0].selectedDeliveryOption.handle;
      setSelectedDeliveryOption(handle);
    }
  });

  console.log('deliveryGroups', deliveryGroups)
  console.log('selectedDeliveryOption', selectedDeliveryOption)

  const handleShippingChange = (val) => {
    setShippingAccountInfo(val)
  }

  const applyAttributeChange = useApplyAttributeChange();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (shippingAccountInfo) {
      // Update the checkout line item with the VAT number attribute
      async function updateShippingAttribute() {
        let res = await applyAttributeChange({
          type: 'updateAttribute',
          key: 'shipping_info',
          value: shippingAccountInfo,
        });
      }

      updateShippingAttribute()
    }
  }, [shippingAccountInfo, applyAttributeChange]);


  return (
    <>
      <TextField
        label="Shipping Account Info: (Enter your carrier and account number)"
        name="shipping_account_info"
        value={shippingAccountInfo}
        onChange={(str) => handleShippingChange(str)}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```